# SpriteKit textures mapping in iOS

Tags: sprite-kit

Is it possible in sprite-kit game that if one moveable texture comes and strikes with other texture, it should come over of it instead of colliding with it.

Comment: Your question is pretty ambiguos, but I am going to guess that you just need to set the collisionBitMask to 0

Comment: texture mapping in sprite kit,
have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture